# How to remove opencv libraries from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, opencv

I installed `opencv` with `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`
I want to uninstall now, as I already have `opencv`. So, I now have 2 versions of `opencv`

Comment: `sudo apt remove libopencv-dev libopencv`?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 This only makes sense if you installed OpenCV manually by copying the files somewhere. But if you installed it using the package manager, it's a horrible idea.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Well, I agree, but as she's asked this question, I get it that she must have tried all other options including `dpkg` and `apt-get purge`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove packages if you installed the package using apt-get, by typing apt-get remove "packagename"(remove quotes).

Additionally you can use whereis command(if memory serves me correctly on ubuntu) by using "whereis packagename" and it should point you to where the conflicting package is, sometimes it is installed within the /usr/bin or the /opt directory  , so you can remove that directory manually.

Food for thought if your after a particular file you can use the find command to find the library as well "find packagenameoranyfile"